# How to prevent premature painting of MemoEdit control when the form is loading

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How to prevent premature painting of MemoEdit control when the form is loading? 
I have a form which is `DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking.ControlContainer`.
Red area in the pic.1 is the devexpress `LayoutControl` which consists of a bunch of LayoutControlItems, almost all of them have a TextEdit editors, but the second one from top is MemoEdit.

[image: form with controls]

In the pic.2 is the what i see when the form is loading (after i called `Show()`).
As you can see, other controls are not drawn or displayed at the moment, but the MemoEdit do. I tried to use `LockWindowUpdate`, `Begin/End Update`, `SuspendLayout` but isn't working. 
I would like to know what are reasons of this behaviour.
[image: Form with memo edit]

I want to specify something. Even when form is loaded and the LayoutControl was once filled with controls, MemoEdit still doing strange things, for example when I am switch between horizontal tabs (pic. 3 and pic. 4). At the moment when I select tab, that was already once "loaded" MemoEdit starts painting at old tab.
[image] 
[image]

Comment: What is expected behavior? I guess you just want to hide container and show it somewhere after, but I suspect you are doing something wrong, e.g. populating data from database during form construction or something.

Comment: Which event of the form are you handling? And how?

Comment: @Sinatr the expected behavior is not to see painting of MemoEdit control. I can't understand why is this problem happens only with MemoEdit, other controls do not draw early...

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič Method OnLoad of DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking.ControlContainer calls event Load of form. In Load handler I create a LayoutControl, dynamically add layout control items on it and then I add this LayoutControl to the tab page of the tab control.

Comment: Do you have any blocking code in those events?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič What do you mean by "blocking code"? Code that prevents visual updates? I have tried to use various of approaches like LockWindowUpdate, Begin / EndUpdate, WM_SETREDRAW but it's doesnt help me.

Comment: I mean code that takes a while to execute. Maybe retrieving data from database or something similar.

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič It is possible, but this happens only once, after the data was loaded, other time it's wont access database. I edited my post with examples when the form and data are already loaded, and I just switch between tabs. At this point, the control also begins to draw prematurely

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič I found out that MemoEdit uses winforms textbox to paint. I tried to replace memoedit with textbox and saw that nothing changed! It seems to be a textbox painting issue and I don't know how to prevent it..

Comment: You shoud show your code.

Comment: Is this an Mdi child form? If not, you can override the XtraForm's FormShowMode property to AfterInitialization to prevent form/control flickering. 

protected override FormShowMode ShowMode => FormShowMode.AfterInitialization;